# How to include .h of C-style in .cpp when global variables are defined in it?

Tags: c++, c, include, global-variables

I want to include a global .h file into my .cpp, but it is in C-style.

In it, global variables are defined like:

```
 int a;    
 int b;
```

Which causes error.

How can I change it to be compatible with my .cpp file?

Comment: It is a linker error? Please post the error that is emitted.

Comment: I would convert that to .cpp and make a .h filled with `extern int a; ...`

Comment: ./debug\moc_fcommand_dlg.o:moc_command_dlg.cpp:(.bss+0x43100): multiple definition of `ParameterSTATUS'

Comment: Im guessing the error is about multiply defined object because of including this .h in many cpps?

Comment: Yes, it is included in many cpps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Remove the definition from the header file.
- Declare them as `extern` in the header file & define the variables in (exactly)one cpp file.
- Include the header file in whichever cpp file which wants to access the variables.

If you define a variable in header file, you will end up violating the **One definition rule** and encounter linking errors.